# Get the filename from bash script recursively using find

Tags: bash, directory-traversal

I am trying retrieve the filename from the find command recursively. This command prints all the filenames with full path

```
> for f in $(find -name '*.png'); do echo "$f";done          
> ./x.png
> ./bg.png
> ./s/bg.png
```

But when i try to just get the name of the file using these commands, it prints

```
for f in $(find -name '*.png'); do echo "${f##*/}";done                                                                                                       
bg.png
```

and

```
for f in $(find -name '*.png'); do echo $(basename $f);done   
bg.png
```

It omits other 2 files. I am new to shell scripting. I couln't figure out whats wrong with this one.

**EDIT:**

THis is what i have actually wanted.

1. I want to loop through a directory recursively and find all png images
2. send it to pngnq for RGBA compression
3. It outputs the new file with `orgfilename-nq8.png`
4. send it to pngcrush and rename and generate a new file (org file will be overwritten )
5. remove  new file

i have a code which works on a single directory

```
for f in *.png; do pngnq -f -n 256 "$f" && pngcrush "${f%.*}"-nq8.png "$f";rm "${f%.*}"-nq8.png; done
```

I want to do this recursively

Comment: If you want to know why it wasn't doing what you wanted: You must have been using it as `for f in "$(find -name '*.png')"; ...` (with quotes), thats my guess, or you have changed `IFS`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do :

```
find -name '*.png' -printf '%f\n'
```

If you want to run something for each files :

```
find -name '*.png' -printf '%f\n' |
while read file; do
    # do something with "$file"
done
```

Or with `xargs` :

```
find -name '*.png' -printf '%f\n' | xargs -n1 command
```

Be sure you cannot use `find` directly like this :

```
find -name '*.png' -exec command {} +
```

or

```
find -name '*.png' -exec bash -c 'do_something with ${1##*/}' -- {} \;
```

Search `-printf` on http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find or in

```
man find | less +/^' *-printf'
```

Comment: this prints all the file names. But i need a way to loop throug each files for further processing. Thats why i used for with find. how to do that?

Comment: What do you want to do for each filenames ? Anyway, see my edited POST

Comment: - 1st want to pass the file to one external program to process. 2 - It outputs another file in some new filename (filename-xxxx.png). 3. I want to retrive the new file name based on pattern and replace the first one with it. 4. remove the generated file

Comment: I can give you my paypal account if you want me to do your script. Or use what I provides to learn yourself, that's a good start. ;)

Comment: Mate, dont patronize. i didnt want you to write entire code for me. I wanted to tell you my context what i am working on to clarify. Thats all. Anyway thanks for your help. Its really useful.

Comment: For those wanting to print the full path use `find -name '*.py' -printf '%h/%f\n'`